# SQL query for fetching one maximum value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, max

Hello stackoverflow :D

I am building an android application with a listview that requires a certain sorting, since it could be reshuffled. So i have a sorting column in my database that holds the position of each value in the database. Now, whenever i create a new element in my list, i want its sort value to be the `maximum+1`, so it will be on the end of the list. Problem is, I don't know how to write a raw query that will return one value, and to check it as well to make sure a value was retrieved at all (the database might be empty).

My efforts so far:

```
Cursor sortcursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + KEY_SORT + ") FROM " + TABLE_CASTING + " WHERE " + KEY_USER + "='" + username + "';", null);
int maxSort = sortcursor.getInt(sortcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SORT));
maxSort++;
cv.put(KEY_SORT, maxSort);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case cursor has only one column, so you should use `sortcursor.getInt(0)` instead of `sortcursor.getInt(sortcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SORT))`. Try the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + KEY_SORT + ") FROM " + TABLE_CASTING + " WHERE " + KEY_USER + "='" + username + "';", null);
int maxSort = 0;

if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst() && !cursor.isNull(0)) {
            maxSort = cursor.getInt(0) + 1;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

cv.put(KEY_SORT, maxSort);
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will work, although note that it is written in MYSQL not sqllite, but I assume the same functions are available.  I've done it for just inserting the next order value into a table, returns 1 if the table is empty and increments the value by 1 if it is not. The second sub-query returns the order, but I found it was handy to combine it with the insert.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (order_column_name) 
VALUES ( 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(tn.order_column_name) IS NULL THEN 1 
     ELSE MAX(tn.order_column_name)+1 END
     AS order_column_name FROM table_name tn
     ORDER BY tn.order_column_name DESC LIMIT 1)
);
```